# I have a list of datetime, agentName and roleType in a spreadsheet (gdocs) - is there a way to export these to google calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

As the title says, we're building out rotations for 8 different job roles for our agents. I have 3 seperate variables: Name, Time, and RoleType where time is a 2 week date range.

I was using AppScripts and made some headway but it's not really doing what I want.

Is there an easy way to create a google calendar event with the agents name, over that two week time frame and with the roletype info in the invite?

this is what I've built so far:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("A21").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);


  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:X19").getValues();
  
  
  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++){
  
  
  var shift = signups [x];
 
  var startTime = shift [0];
  var endTime= shift [1];
  var dataValDor = shift [2];

  eventCal.createEvent(dataValDor, startTime, endTime);
  }
}
```

This was taken and modified from [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/g-suite-pro-tip-how-to-automatically-add-a-schedule-from-google-sheets-into-calendar)

However I guess my data is laid out badly as it just created about 10 different entries for each agent.

Comment: Your `signups` has 18 rows so I would expect 18 events created.  What is it you expect or want?

Comment: hey if you dont mind sharing, could I get a screenshot of your database (A2:X19)? So I can see how I modify your code. Thx